# Destroy a session and automatically loads the page

Tags: php, session

I want to destroy my session after 3 minutes I'm doing that, but the problem is that when I reloads the page then it will take me back to previous page but what I want is that it automatically reloads previous page after 3 minutes(i.e when my session is destroyed)

PHP:

```
session_start();

            if($_REQUEST['btn_logout'])
            {   
                $_SESSION['time']=time()+180;
                $_SESSION['name']="";
                header("location:login.php?msg=Logout Successfully");
            }                               
            if ($_SESSION['time']&&time()-$_SESSION['time']&gt;180)
            {                                   
                $d=$_SESSION['data'];
                $email=$_SESSION['email'];
                $count=0;
                for($i=0 ;$i&lt;count($email);$i++)
                {                                       
                    foreach($d as $key)
                    {                                           
                        $count++;
                        if($_REQUEST['name']==$key['user_email'] && $_REQUEST['pass']==$key['user_password'])
                        {                                               
                            if(count($email)==1)
                            {                                                   
                                session_unset();
                                session_destroy();
                                header("location:login.php?msg=Your Session got expired");
                            }
                            else
                            {                                               
                                $arr=array_keys($_SESSION['data']);                                                 
                                unset($_SESSION['data'][$arr[$count-1]]);
                                unset($_SESSION['email'][$arr[$count-1]]);
                            }                                                                                           

                        }                                       
                    }                                   
                }           

            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could leverage the *unofficial* but widely supported `Refresh` header:

```
header('Refresh: 180; url=login.php');
//               ^^^ 3 minutes in seconds.
```

However, it would make much more sense to have the client handle this with JavaScript. Anything from a weak solution like literally waiting 3 seconds and redirecting to polling the server every 10-15 seconds to check if the session has expired.

Comment: Anywhere before output starts (e.g. at the top).

Comment: It said "location=login.php" was not found on server.

Comment: Perhaps replace login.php with something that does exist on your server.

Comment: login.php do exist on my server, when i put header('Refresh: 180; location:login.php'); It didn't work.

Comment: Sorry it should be `url=`.

Comment: i just put header('Refresh: 180; login.php'); and it works btw thanks.